# How to restrict users from editing certain fields on opportunity layout?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, validation, configuration

Alright, so these are things i have to work with :

Assuming user u1, u2 and u3 (all have the same profiles),

1. Same opp record type is assigned to all of them.
2. If a custom field (sub_record_type__c) is = 'Subscription', then u3 should only be able change the 'Stage' and 'Close Date' of the opportunity. u1 and u2 and proceed as usual.

Now, currently, I have explored the option of dynamic page layouts, but it does not work for standard objects. So, currently, I have implemented a solution where I have a permission set assigned to u1 and u2, and check in the before update trigger to fire an error if u3 tries to change anything other than 'stage' and 'opportunity'. But this is not an elegant solution that I like as it is in the code and needs exception fields to be maintained.

Also, validation rules are a no go, as we will have to have a validation to check every field change for the user and maintain it for every field addition.

Is there another config way to solve this?

Comment: Hi, May I know, What is the OWD permission for the Opportunity object in your org?

Comment: The OWD for Opp should be private.

Comment: Let me know, If you have the opportunity "X" which has custom field (sub_record_type__c) is = 'Subscription', Then user u3 need having edit access for the fields `Stage` and `Close Date`. What about the remaining fields access for users u1 and u2? Those are all need to able to update remaining fields for the opportunity "X" except "Close date" and "Stage" ?

Comment: @MohanRaj Thanks, yes u1 and u2 will have access to the regular fields as per the FLS provided to the profile.

Comment: dynamic page layouts for Opportunity was added in Winter 23

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, You can't done this requirement due to it's complex behavior. Since the Opportunities`field` (`Stage` and `Closed Won`) access has been stick with `Profile` or `Permission set`. So **you can't provide and restrict those fields access based on any record values in that object on Salesforce**.

> You can only open the object/field access for any user by profile/permission  set. You can't restrict any existing Std. object/field access based on record value for that particular object.

The above is a Salesforce core concept of it's design.

Simply In Salesforce,

- You can restrict record access for any specific user by `Restriction rule` or `Role Hierarchy` or `OWD` settings.
- You can open the record record access for any specific user by `Sharing rule` or `Role Hierarchy` or `OWD` settings.
- You can Open the object/field access into any specific user by `Profile` or `Permission set`.
- You can't restrict any specific field access based on record value.

Thanks :(